# How to mount a USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive

I have a USB drive that used to mount with another computer, but won't appear when it should with another. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and the drive should appear under "Places". Here's the output of **`dmesg`**:

```
1:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[293385.423359] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
...
[293445.824471] exe (29828): /proc/29828/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/29828/oom_score_adj instead.
[299465.937891] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
```

Update: new lines added are

```
Aug 14 17:47:23 ubuntu kernel: [  128.502091] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 2 if 0 alt 1 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x1004
Aug 14 17:47:23 ubuntu kernel: [  128.502416] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
Aug 14 17:47:25 ubuntu kernel: [  130.703847] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Aug 14 17:47:25 ubuntu kernel: [  130.703909] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
Aug 14 17:47:25 ubuntu kernel: [  130.703935] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
Aug 14 17:47:30 ubuntu kernel: [  135.755667] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
Aug 14 17:47:32 ubuntu kernel: [  137.450048] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Aug 14 17:47:35 ubuntu kernel: [  140.788119] usb 7-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'usb' sets config #1
```

Comment: Can you run `tail --follow /var/log/kern.log`, connect your drive, and post the new lines added afterwards.

Comment: Did those lines you just pasted appear **after** you have plugged the drive?

Comment: Also, you can try [my function posted here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18064/if-i-connect-a-physical-device-how-can-i-ever-know-which-device-file-belongs-to/18070#18070) to see if the drive was deteced. (You can just paste it in terminal, then about 20 sec. after plugging the drive in, run `listusbdisks`).

Comment: Thank you rozcietrzewiacz I will keep checking and trying to define is this is a faulty drive but I already could use it with ext4 and then these problems appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking on /media,

on my system (i'm running Kubuntu 11.04) all the floppy, CDROM and USB gets mounted on /media
so you'd like to check there

Comment: It doesn't appear but I'm getting some logfile indications what happens so I'll see where this goes.

Answer (score 1):

Give the drive a few minutes to appear. If it was unplugged without being properly dismounted, or the physical shocks of being transported have caused surface damage, the OS may be doing a background [fsck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) on the drive. If that's happening, it won't show up in the UI until that finishes.

Comment: Few minutes is absolutely too much. Dmesg should react within *at most* about 10-20 seconds so it is clearly not the problem. Also no fsck can take place before the kernel identifies the hardware (as indicated by `dmesg`).