# How to repartition pendrive again?

Tags: partition, opensuse, usb-drive

My 8GB pendrive originally contained only a FAT partition, but I tried to install OpenSUSE 11.4 on it. I created a 200MB partition for `/boot` and the rest was for the root partition.

Despite the minimal size of basic OS installation (490MB) I got errors during install stating the rpm couldn't unpack packages (around 20% of the install process). After several such errors (which included bash rpm) I gave up, and restarted computer.

Now I have a pendrive with no partitions at all, and I am unable to create any. `fdisk` fails with error "fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdc: Invalid argument", `gpart` fails with error "Floating point exception", Windows 7 refuses to format it, and when I check the properties I see capacity 0, used 0, available 0 space, and so on.

How can I re-partition this disk?

#### Edit 1

dmesg output after inserting pendrive:

```
[ 9980.463056] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[ 9980.579456] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6544
[ 9980.579460] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9980.579462] usb 1-1: Product: TransMemory
[ 9980.579464] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[ 9980.579466] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000FEAFB7A60C971F3D40B8A
[ 9980.579916] scsi12 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 9981.580536] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 9981.580738] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 9981.585276] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[ 9981.585279] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 9981.585283] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 9981.585287] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 9981.585766] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 9981.585769] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 65 44 09 30
[ 9981.585772] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 9981.590519] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[ 9981.590522] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 9981.590525] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 9981.590529] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 9981.591780] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 9981.591783] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

#### Edit 2

Thank you for all responses. Just one clarification -- it wasn't just a try to run a distro for pendrive (however I did it before and it worked). I keep linux on pendrive just for some tests, I run it once a year maybe. But today I tried to get valid boot partition, the rest of the system was not important. But of course, if this is pendrive death case, what I wanted to do with it in future didn't matter for this poor thing :-)

Comment: What does `dmesg` show when connecting the drive? Other syslog/kernel/messages?

Comment: @Caleb, I will update my post with the messages. What do you mean by syslog/kernel messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that your drive experienced some kind of hardware failure. The problem isn't the partitions, the problem was encountered when the drive decided to die on you. The original errors you saw during install were probably it failing to write because the disk failed to respond correctly to commands.

You can try putting it in a different machine with a different USB controller, maybe it will come to life. If you do it will probably show the partitions as they were but with corrupted data in the one you were installing to. Unfortunately once a flash drive starts to go bad it's probably a loosing battle.

Comment: Thank you, I tried several computers now, no success everywhere, the pendrive died apparently.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it seems that you've just killed your pendrive while trying to install a normal* distro onto it. (See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Memory_wear) on why this is a bad idea.)

If there is any chance of bringing your pendrive back to life, it would involve destroying current partitioning. You can try doing that using `dd`. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=4096 count=100` should be more than enough - but remember that **it will destroy your current partitions**, so make sure that you want it and that `/dev/sdc` is the pendrive. (You can use the [function recognizing external disks I posted here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18064/if-i-connect-a-physical-device-how-can-i-ever-know-which-device-file-belongs-to/18070#18070).)

If you are desperate to retrieve the data from the pendrive, use [the testdisk tool](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) - it might be already on your install or at least in the repos. Run it like this: `testdisk /dev/sdc` and proceed to *Analyse* and then *Restore*. Read the manual in case of doubt.

<sub>*) By "normal" I mean a distribution that was designed to reside on a hard drive. You should not do so - it is risky since typical distributions do not care that much about the ammount of disk writes. But your situation might indicate you were actually lucky to face this failure during installation and not after some time of system usage (see also Caleb's comment).</sub>

Comment: That the drive died is likely. That the action of installing a normal distro on it did this is UNLIKELY. Extended use of a normal distro on it maybe, but the guy is just trying to install the first time! The drive just died, installing a different distro wouldn't have changed it's fate.

Comment: It is all a matter of probability. The more writes are performed, the higher the risk. Each distro has its own install procedure that may involve more or fewer disk writes to install packages. But what i meant was mainly to indicate that there are *special* distributions (like [Tin Hat](http://opensource.dyc.edu/tinhat) or liveUSBs, [pentoo](http://www.pentoo.ch/) for example) that are *designed* to live on a pendrive and make as little writes to it as possible.

Comment: I know of no distro that abuses disks to the point of hitting 100k write cycles on a 490MB installation. If write cycles is the reason it's failing (not certain but probable) then the disk was near-death anyway. True there are distros optimized for this use, but the OP didn't kill it just because he didn't pick one of those for FIRST INSTALLATION. He would have contributed to it's early demise by using it too much like that, but cut him some slack :)

Comment: @Caleb Alright. I didn't mean to blame macias too much - this stuff happens. I meant to say it was a bad idea. See also my edit (footnote) - where I tried to explain it a bit. But I know it is possible to run a system off a pendrive - I do so myself on my little home server :D (and I know it is risky, so I keep my backups).

Comment: Thank you, I don't want to restore anything, I want to create new partitions. dd didn't work -- "dd: writing `/dev/sdc': No space left on device". What strikes my odd, despite system got info it is Toshiba pendrive, it is not listed anymore as TOSxxx but as generic USB Mass Storage. Maybe it is really dead, pity :-(

Comment: Yes, seems more and more like a dead one. You can take the way of last resort - to unplug it, reboot, then plug back again and run testdisk.

Answer (score 2):

Try the application Gparted. You can either install it in Linux or use it from a LiveCD - http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

BUT be careful. It is possible to partition your Hard Drive by mistake!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly both GParted and QtParted do not even recognize the pendrive (the system lists it as /dev/sdc). And so I am unable to alter pendrive partition in any way.